# Super simple Python 3.x library for accessing http requests

Tags: http, python-3.x, httprequest

Is there a very simple way to access the direct text/bytes of an http request in Python 3.x? Similar to what you would get out of Telnet or something like that. I'm looking for something I can set up to listen on a port, accept the request and directly read what comes across. It wouldn't define it was looking for POST or GET, etc., just the raw values:

Sample value:

```
    GET /index.html/?=request HTTP/1.1
    Host: www.example.com
    User-Agent: Safari/4.0
```

Comment: Sometimes right after I post I go out and find exactly the answer I was looking for. Amazing what happens when you decide to consult the documentation! I found pretty much what I'm looking for here: https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/socketserver.html?highlight=tcp#socketserver.BaseServer.get_request

Answer (score 0):

The library I was looking for is [here](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/socketserver.html?highlight=tcp#socketserver.BaseServer.get_request). The code in particular I was looking for is this:

```
import socketserver

class MyTCPHandler(socketserver.BaseRequestHandler):
    """
    The RequestHandler class for our server.

    It is instantiated once per connection to the server, and must
    override the handle() method to implement communication to the
    client.
    """

def handle(self):
    # self.request is the TCP socket connected to the client
    self.data = self.request.recv(1024).strip()
    print("{} wrote:".format(self.client_address[0]))
    print(self.data)
    # just send back the same data, but upper-cased
    self.request.sendall(self.data.upper())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    HOST, PORT = "localhost", 9999

    # Create the server, binding to localhost on port 9999
    server = socketserver.TCPServer((HOST, PORT), MyTCPHandler)

    # Activate the server; this will keep running until you
    # interrupt the program with Ctrl-C
    server.serve_forever()
```